# jQuery fix() function causes hang in IE7/8

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer, drupal, internet-explorer-8

We're about to launch our last new Drupal 6 site (all future projects will be Drupal 7). Drupal 6 requires a version of jQuery no greater than 1.3.2., so that's what we're running.

In Internet Explorer 7 and 8, almost every page load hangs for 5 to 10 seconds in the middle of loading images. When I use the Developer Tools profiler, I find that a a single call to a function called fix() is responsible for the hang.

It's hard to Google for a function called "fix", but I found a couple of posts at jquery.com: [a bug that was fixed in jQuery 1.2.1](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1871) and [a forum thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fix-is-slow) that is inside baseball and frustratingly free of context and that kind of peters out. One fix is benchmarked in that thread and it shows only modest improvements in IE performance.

So what does this fix() function do, anyway? I can tell it has something to do with event handling. Is there something I can do to speed it up or (less likely) eliminate it?

Comment: My problem involves Drupal but it's not really a Drupal *question*, so I put it here instead of on Drupal Answers. Apologies in advance if that was a poor decision.

Comment: Have you followed the source to look into where the fix() function lives?